# Category of properties (eg. from topologies to semantic fields)?

Tags: general-topology, logic, reference-request, category-theory

> **Question 1.** I'd like to know if there is a name and a known use in the literature for categories defined by taking, for example, as objects some "*individuals*" or "*points*" or "*words*" and as connecting morphisms shared "*properties*", shared "*sets*" or common "*semantic fields*".

I'll give the exact definition I have in mind for topological spaces and an attempt for the case of logic. This first question is restricted to the use of this category in topology and category theory.

> **Question 2** This construction provides a way to build categories from topological spaces and, **it seems to me**, to represent the relational nature of the meaning of words. Is this last use adopted by mathematical-inclined linguists? If not, do exists similar uses in the mathematical treatment of semantic in pure mathematics (model theory)?

**Disclaimer.** When I talk about *semantic fields*, and treating of the "meaning" I'm referring informally to natural language where I'd define semantic fields as extensions of a semantic property, e.g. ${\bf sea\,lifeform}:{\rm shark} \to {\rm coral}$ and ${\bf tailed}:{\rm shark} \to {\rm dog}$. I don't really know if there are linguists using categories to model semantics and if they do it following roughly the method I'm describing.

---

**Topological space example.**

Let $(X,\kappa)$ be a topological space defined by its closed sets $\kappa$. Conceptually I want to define a  category where for points $x,y$ the hom-set ${\rm Hom}(x,y) $ is the collection of closed sets containing both $x$ and $y$.

Define the category $X^\sigma$ as follows: let  $\mathfrak T(x)=\{U\in\kappa\,\,|\,\, x\in  U\}$

> - $X^\sigma_0:=X$ is the set of points of the top. space.
> - $X^\sigma_1=\{f\in X^2\times \kappa\,\,|\,\,\pi_0(f)\in\pi_1(f)\times \pi_1(f)\}$ is the set of morphisms. In other words I'd like to define a morphism $x\to y$ as a triple $(x,y,U)$ with $x,y\in U$ closed set.
> - Domain and codomains are the two projections of the points. The identity is $$\displaystyle x\mapsto (x,x,\bigcap_{U\in \mathfrak T(x)} U)$$
> - Given $f=(x,y,U)$ and $g=(y,z,W)$ the set $U\cup W$ is open and we have a morphism and $g\circ f=(x,z,U\cup W)$.

This is a category because: domain, codomain and identity behave well; union is associative and $(x,y,U)\circ(x,x,I_x)=(x,y,U)$ because $z\in I_x=\bigcap_{V\in \mathfrak T(x)} V$ and $x\in U$ imply $z\in U$.

---

**Logic (attempt).**

In the previous example we can include the case of the topological space $(X,\mathcal P(X))$ and in this case we are working with shared (extensions) of properties. In the case of logic we could define composition as $\lor$ and as identity $x\mapsto Z=x$ and the morphisms as $${\rm Hom}(x,y)=\{(x,y,\varphi(Z))\,|\, \varphi(x)\land \varphi(y)\}$$

Here identity law and associative work only up to $\iff$: $(x,y,\varphi(Z))\circ(x,x,Z=x)=(x,y,\varphi(Z)\lor z=x)$ and

$$(\varphi(Z)\lor Z=x)\Leftrightarrow \varphi(Z)$$

1. if for $z$ we have that $\varphi(z)$ is true then $\varphi(z)\lor z=x$ is true;
2. if for $z$ the conjunction $\varphi(z)\lor z=x$ is true then $\varphi(z)$ is true, and we have concluded, or $z=x$ is true. In that case, since $\varphi(x)$ is true by hypothesis, we conclude that $\varphi(z)$ is true.

Comment: @NoahSchweber isn't that way more sophisticated than my example? I mean, In my case I'm not modding out by some eq. relation. I can see that the existence of a path connecting two points implies the existence of a closed set containing both the point (is it the image?). I'd be interested to know if this category I'm defining is related to the fundamental groupoid in some precise sense. For example my case is not a groupoid (probably a dagger category?). On the other hand in the logic example I can imagine some kind of 2-morphisms business going on.

Answer (score 1):

Since a property is shared by two objects $X,Y$ iff it is shared by $Y,X$, we need some sort of symmetry. [Dagger-categories](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dagger_category) come to my mind - as a vast abstraction of your idea. The objects can be anything, the hom-sets are "symmetric" in the sense that there are natural bijections $\hom(X,Y) \cong \hom(Y,X)$. Now just interpret $\hom(X,Y)$ as the set of properties shared by the objects $X$ and $Y$. Maybe you want to add the condition $\mathrm{Mor}(\mathcal{C}) \subseteq P(\mathcal{Ob}(\mathcal{C}))$ as in your first example.

Comment: Well, I see. I already noticed that my examples were special instances of dagger categories. But at first look, I'm ignorant in CT, I see that those are too abstract to settle my question 1. Unless there is some result that makes us able to produce a (generalized?) topological space out of every $\dagger$-category, like an adjoint to my construction, which I'm not sure how to make functorial, btw.

Comment: I see how you recover morphisms-as-properties interpretation, can be a tiny hint, but I'm not sure it's enough specific to settle the first question "*if there is a name and a known use in the literature [...] restricted to the use of this category in topology and category theory*". And given that this does not even touch my second question I'm not sure I can accept this.